# General term of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the general term of $(1,0,-3,0,5,0,-7,\ldots)$ and $(0,2,0,-4,0,6,\ldots)$. I think I can manipulate the general term of the sequence $(1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots)$, but I can't figure it out, Any ideas are welcome. I'm trying to understand sequences on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: $(n+1)\cos(\pi n/2)$ and $(n+1)\sin(\pi n/2)$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in the comments, it would be a good idea to use $\sin$ and $\cos$, since we know they can generate $0,1$ and $-1$. We'll use that

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1,\sin(\pi)=\sin(2\pi)=0,\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})=-1,\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$, from what we get $\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})=1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots$

and

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2})=0,\cos(\pi)=-1,\cos(2\pi)=1,\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x),\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)$, from what we get $\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi)=-\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})=0,1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots$

Now, for the first one, if we want $(1,0,-1,0,1,\ldots)$ to be $(1,0,-3,0,5,\ldots)$ we need to multiply the terms of the sequence by its position, since then we get $(1·1,0·2,-1·3,0·4,1·5,\ldots)=(1,0,-3,0,5,\ldots)$

To do this we just need to multiply the $n$-th term by $n$. So $(1,0,-3,0,5,\ldots)$ is given by $n\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})$

I'll leave to you the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question?